# Clicking repeatedly on the flag button repeats the “waiting” animation

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

When clicking repeatedly on the “flag” button, the “waiting” animation gets displayed as many times as there were clicks.

(To reproduce this, the AJAX response should take longer than expected.)

[image]

I was able to reproduce this again (2013-11-18) on regular answer.

[image]

Comment: This seems to happen on all sites

Comment: I can't reproduce this any more on Super User or here on Web Applications.

Comment: Looks like this has been fixed with the prevention of loading the flag dialogue for more than once in three seconds.

Comment: It should be closed and tagged accordingly then.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot reproduce this, but I'm going to assume it was there initially and someone from SE Team fixed it. Marking this as resolved.